# Collaborative editing for .NET development - what are the possibilities

Tags: .net, eclipse, visual-studio, development-environment

What are the best options for real-time collaborative editing for .NET development? (C#,VB.NET, ASP.NET - not Mono unless it is the best way to get collaboration)

1) Anything possible with visual studio?

2) Collaborative editors?  I know Eclipse has real-time collaboration, but I don't know how far you can combine it with .NET support.

3) Web-based tools?

4) Desktop sharing tools like VNC, NX etc.

---

The main points is that 2 developers in different locations should be able to see edits in real time. Both should be able to edit, or it should be easy to switch control.

Regarding .NET, syntax highlighting etc is better than nothing.

Comment: i just had a google wave plugin idea.

Comment: What about the development using Team  Suite

Answer (score 9):

I've recently found [this tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/99466148-ae68-4bd5-b66b-08bae7423a03)

It looks like [VsAnywhere](http://www.vsanywhere.com/) is exactly what you need

Answer (score 3):

[Cloud9 IDE](http://c9.io/) announced team coloboration feature, but now this feature is haven't released yet

Answer (score 1):

Real-time collaborative edits in IDE is probably not desirable because that would make code uncompilable unless all participants are done at the same time. This means you can't frequently run and test your changes and see your test getting passed. Your edits would block another person and vice versa. A good alternative is continuous integration where you can push code at every time your tests passes and immediately do pull afterwards to get other people's changes. This can be done by simple scripting with most version control systems.

One of the app I frequently use for collaborative code discussion is http://collabedit.com.

Comment: Though you see  Real-Time collaboration in IDE "as-is", what means  behaviour while sharing a project will be exactly the same if you are not sharing a Project, that is like anarchy, not a good idea at all. If you share a Project with other people is to discuss and improve a software piece, and when you finish, you continue your work, is not all/nothing, you do not need to share a project all time, just when is need.

Answer (score 1):

One application that integrates with Visual Studio and allows collaborative code editing is [Source Meet](http://www.sourcemeet.com/)

> Source Meet supports the collaboration of software developers in
>   project teams using Source Meeting. The basis of the collaboration is
>   provided by the familiar Visual Studio™ Editor, by means of which
>   spatially separated documents may be viewed and worked on together. As
>   not just the document contents but also the Visual Studio™ Editor
>   properties such as highlighting or positioning are synchronized in
>   real time, you get the feeling of sitting together in front of one
>   monitor.